# WolframAlpha doesn't recognize the query

Tags: wolframalpha

I need to solve this equation in WolframAlpha

4(x^2-x+1)(-(bx^2 (5x^2-6x+3))/(c(5x^4-6x^3+3x^2-x+1)-a(-x+1))+1) = (4(5x^4-6x^3+3x^2-x+1)(-x+1)(c-a))/(-a(-x+1)+c(5x^4-6x^3+3x^2-x+1))

but it says that it doesn't recognize the query. Does someone know why?

Comment: works for me when I try it on wolfram

Comment: Can you please share with me the output?

Comment: just go to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%28x%5E2-x%2B1%29%28-%28bx%5E2+%285x%5E2-6x%2B3%29%29%2F%28c%285x%5E4-6x%5E3%2B3x%5E2-x%2B1%29-a%28-x%2B1%29%29%2B1%29+%3D+%284%285x%5E4-6x%5E3%2B3x%5E2-x%2B1%29%28-x%2B1%29%28c-a%29%29%2F%28-a%28-x%2B1%29%2Bc%285x%5E4-6x%5E3%2B3x%5E2-x%2B1%29%29

Comment: Well, apart from the fact that the result looks crazy, thanks!! Copying the equation from here must have fixed some weird font problem

Comment: Answer back your question, say how you fixed the problem, then autotick answer validated, so people know you fixed your issue, and how , in case someone have same issue